# Interactive Free viewpoint video

Tags: video, video-processing, video-tracking

I need to create interactive free view point video ,what programming language can be used to do this,and is there any good tutorial.Is there any library package  is already available.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no library's available yet. Its still a developing field.

There are a couple of companies that are trying to make it happen but there doesn't seem to be anything commercially available yet.

There is http://www.doubleme.me and Microsoft.
And lots of research papers.

I would learn C++ and OpenCV if I were you. 
Also be prepared to spend a lot of money on cameras and equipment. 
(Microsoft used 106 Kinect2s for their FVV project!)